# Create and manage the same list from two spots

Tags: usability

I have a feature that can be enabled for different locations.

When the feature is turned on, a part of the feature requires users to create a list.

The feature is turned on in a dialog box. The user turns on the feature, then the list is exposed and the user can start adding things to the list.

He can then repeat the process for all the different locations.

After doing that, the user needs to sometimes manage those lists so I want to create a separate view called Lists where the user can view all the lists created during enabling of the feature.

Is this a good design pattern? Users will basically have two ways to add/remove items from the list:

- Go to the feature settings and manage the list
- Go to a "Manage Lists" page where he can manage all the lists with the option to filter by location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A new page isn't a bad idea, it allows you to see what locations have lists very easily.

You can also add an icon next to the location listing to indicate that it has a list if that helps users more easily identify items that have lists.

[image: location listing with list indicators]

If you want only one page (the feature page) you could add a filter that allows users to only show locations with lists.

[image: location list with filter]

It could even be a button that says "With Lists Only" or whatever you find to work best.

Comment: Thanks!
I find the Manage Lists page to be necessary because, when you enable the feature in the dialog box you can start creating the list for that specific location but after doing that for 10 locations it becomes hard to manage because you will have to edit every feature dialog list. 

So that's why i added the manage list tabs which will aggregate all the lists from all locations in a single, filterable table. 

But the caveat I see is that users will have two ways to access the lists. Open the feature dialog or click the manage lists tab. But i'm not sure if this is a good design...

Comment: @Chris the last design was just an idea, the main idea is what you said plus (optionally) the icon showing that a location has a list (though I just realised that this can be skipped since you already have the item count -_-). But back to your last point. Having multiple entry points is good so long it's relevant to wherever the entry point is placed and it doesn't disrupt the choice hierarchy (i.e. it doesn't ask for attention when it shouldn't). If it feels too off for you, try A/B testing it.